# why assigning instance variable inside method of implemented interface does not work while calling it from another local methods of the same class?

Tags: java, android, oop

I have a class called "A" implements interface "I" like below

```
public interface I<T>{
   void setList(List<T> list)
}

public class A implements I<M>{
   private List<M> mList;

   public void load(){
      //Working on mList....
   }

   public void method(){
      someList;
      I<M> i = this;
      i.setList(someList);
   }

   public void setList(List<M> list){
      this.mList = list;
   }

}

public class M{
   private String str;
}
```

I want to assign value of list to mList and use it wherever inside the class however the value will be assigned inside the overriden method but when I use mList in any other methods like load it does not give me the value.

Comment: No, there's only one member, and you're assigning it, sure enough. You've made a mistake somewhere else, it's not clear from your pseudocode. You should add the code you're using to draw your conclusions that the list is not present.

Comment: Are you using a single thread?

Comment: Please edit your question to make it a [mcve] - especially you should not omit the code in the `load()` method where you say you are getting errors!

Comment: Avoid one-letter variable (`i`) and class names (`M`), they're confusing. You left out a semicolon in the interface. Your example code should compile successfully unless you're asking about a compiler error, in which case it should show (only) that error. Don't use `this.` before method calls, nor assign aliases to `this` (`i = this`). Don't name a method `method`. Implementation warts in variable names (the `m` in `mList`) are evil. Avoid embodying implementation in identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could find the solution I was supposed to do like below

```
public interface I<T>{
   void setList(List<T> list)
}

public class A implements I<M>{
   private List<M> mList;
   I<M> i;

   public A(){
      this.i = this;
   }

   public void load(){
      //Working on mList....
   }

   public void method(){
      someList;
      i.setList(someList);
   }

   public void setList(List<M> list){
      this.mList = list;
   }

}

public class M{
   private String str;
}
```